Angular 17 ESBuild Configuration for environment variables
Just migrated from Angular 15 to the 17. And currently it is possible to build and serve with esbuild instead of webpack. With webpack there was a way use a custom webpack config for things like, enviroment variables:
enter image description here
Where in webpack.partial.js I can add my enviroment variables. I wasn't able to find something similar for the esbuild.
The page is blank and I have this error. Upon search on the main.js the COMMIT_SHA_SHOR or even the package.json version(environment variables ) that I need are still missing
(https://i.sstatic.net/f82DR16t.png)
Below my Angular version:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/8v8knCTK.png
I've tried this sugggestions but without any results
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/22503#issuecomment-2034430649

Please don't add screenshots of code and errors, you should copy and paste them as text instead. Texts inside screenshots are inaccessible for anyone with visual impairments. Also it unnecessarily consumes bandwidth. Only use images if absolutely necessary, i.e. a screenshot to illustrate an issue in the UI. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

You are already using a third party tool to customize the webpack config @angular-builders/custom-webpack. Now that you are using ESBuild, you need to use @angular-builders/custom-esbuild instead.
In ESBuild, you can use define to add environment variables, see the docs.
